# How to import tables from excel to R for Chi Square

Tags: r, excel

I have an excel file with the format below. For each 2x2 table I would like to calculate Chi square in R. The orange columns are + test and blue - test, the rows are self explanatory. What is the most efficient way to import to do this in R please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmKSy.png)

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: This is really two questions: (1) how to read excel files into R ([`[r] read excel file`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+read%20excel%20file)); and (2) how to run a chi-squared test on that data ([`[r] chi squared test`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+chi+squared+test)). Hope those links help.